# Listing of pass and failed test cases in Go

Tags: go

In go language , is it possible to show both the pass testcase and failed testcase in the console.

Suppose , I have a file test.go , which has 4 testcases , out of which 2 have passed and 2 have failed.

When we use t.Errorf(), function and then command "go test", then only the failed testcases with description is displayed.

So , Is there a way to show number of testcases passed and failed?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
go test -v
```

Use `go test help` for a list of available flags.

http://golang.org/cmd/go/#hdr-Description_of_testing_flags

Comment: Use `go help test` or  `go test -h` to see documentation and available flags.

Comment: Updated link for testing flags: https://pkg.go.dev/cmd/go#hdr-Testing_flags

Answer (score 6):

I use `grep` for it:

```sh
make test | grep FAIL
```

Answer (score 1):

I use `rg` or `grep` with `sed`

```bash
go test --run Test | rg FAIL: | sed 's/^--- FAIL: //' | sed 's/ ([[:digit:]]*.[[:digit:]]*s)//'
```

This only prints the name of the failing tests, which I can then redirect to a file or clipboard to further investigate.